# Where can I enter the api key in google-map-react?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I have been unable to get the map to display. The code is:

```
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";

const Mapa = ({ center, zoom }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
      <div style={{ width: "400px", height: "400px" }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          defaultCenter={center}
          defaultZoom={zoom}
        ></GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
Mapa.defaultProps = {
  center: {
    lat: 45.1436,
    lng: 18.2899,
  },
  zoom: 7,
};

export default Mapa;
```

There are no errors in the console...
Any help would be great!

Comment: You probably left out your API key of course, but worth checking that you have it in your project. You can try the prop `onGoogleApiLoaded={console.log}` to log to the console and make sure it's loading as you expect.

Comment: did you log your props to see if you have the values ? ```console.log(props)``` above the return ?

Comment: @DeanJames Can you tell me how to use that prop exactly?

Comment: Just add it underneath `defaultZoom={zoom}`.

Answer (score 1):

let's try:

```
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";

const Mapa = ({ center, zoom }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
      <div style={{ width: "400px", height: "400px" }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "  " }}
          defaultCenter={center}
          defaultZoom={zoom}
        ></GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
Mapa.defaultProps = {
  center: {
    lat: 45.1436,
    lng: 18.2899,
  },
  zoom: 7,
};

export default Mapa;
```